# Parse JSON response using shell script

Tags: json, linux, shell

```
{
    "PlatformID": 1024,
    "SystemId": 11640,
    "SystemName": "010.10.10.10",
    "DomainName": null,
    "AccountId": 15631,
    "AccountName": "merg1",
    "AccountNameFull": "merg1",
    "ApplicationID": null,
    "ApplicationDisplayName": null,
    "MaximumReleaseDuration": 120,
    "MaxReleaseDurationDays": 0,
    "MaxReleaseDurationHours": 2,
    "MaxReleaseDurationMinutes": 0,
    "InstanceName": "",
    "DefaultReleaseDuration": 120,
    "DefaultReleaseDurationDays": 0,
    "DefaultReleaseDurationHours": 2,
    "DefaultReleaseDurationMinutes": 0,
    "LastChangeDate": "2019-08-21T10:53:25.237",
    "NextChangeDate": null,
    "IsChanging": false,
    "IsISAAccess": false,
    "PreferredNodeID": "3ef3e7c7-5851-451b-b1a4-c62556b588ce"
}
```

I am looking for "SystemId and AccountId" from the above JSON response without using jq tool.

Kindly help with the shell script. Thank you.

Comment: What's preventing you from using the `jq` tool?

Comment: that jq package needs to be installed and its not installed in the linux box, jq command not found

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parsing JSON with Unix tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955505/parsing-json-with-unix-tools)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `grep` on the following usage.

```
grep -E -- 'AccountId|SystemId' t.txt | awk '{print $2}'
11640,
15631,
```

Or If would you like to use `jq` you can try this one.

```
cat t.txt | jq '.AccountId , .SystemId'
15631
11640
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure of the structure of the json file, and the following steps should work (this requires that a pair key and value is always on the same line -- if not we need to remove any white space before and after the colon)

1. separate each field to a separate line
2. use `grep` to extract the line that has `SystemId` or `AccountId`
3. use `awk` to extract the second field in that line (delimited by the colon)

```
cat a.json | tr , '\n' | grep SystemId | awk -F ':' '{print $2}'
11640

cat a.json | tr , '\n' | grep AccountId | awk -F ':' '{print $2}'
15631
```

---

Edited: if json is in a varaible, and there is a need to save the output to variable:

```
#!/bin/bash

JSON=$(cat a.json)


sysID=$(echo $JSON | tr , '\n' | grep SystemId | awk -F ':' '{print $2}')
accID=$(echo $JSON | tr , '\n' | grep AccountId | awk -F ':' '{print $2}')

echo "System ID = $sysID, Account ID = $accID"

# output
# System ID =  11640, Account ID =  15631
```

Comment: How to I do the same thing if the json is in the variable not in the file? and once parse I need to assign it to variable like sysID and accID instead of print

Comment: if the json is in the variable, use `echo $var` instead of `cat a.json`. To assign it to a variable, use `$( )`. I will update the answer to give more details.

Comment: Super its working, this is what i was looking for... thank you so much...!

Answer (score 0):

```
sysID=$(echo $JSON | tr , '\n' | grep SystemId | awk -F ':' '{print $2}')
accID=$(echo $JSON | tr , '\n' | grep AccountId | awk -F ':' '{print $2}')

echo "System ID = $sysID, Account ID = $accID"
```

This worked for me...! without using jq tool